# How To Modify Visual Studio's C# .Net Core Console App Project Template

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-templates

As a student I find myself having to create tons of C# .Net Core Console Applications in Visual Studio. The thing is I also find myself having to use the `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Linq` namespaces in virtually all my projects. But the only namespace that is included in Visual Studio's default C# .Net Core Console App template is `System`, so it is just annoying have to add those two namespaces every time I create a new project. So can I edit that template to include the two namespaces, and if so how? Also if I can I would also like to remove the project's namespace that is generated since all the projects are just a single file and I really don't think that that namespace is needed, it just clutters the file a little bit. And maybe also remove the `Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")` that is generated.

Ideally I would like the `Program.cs` file that is created when I use the template to look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {

    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
using System;

namespace PROJECT_NAME
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a template in Visual Studio.

- Open New Console App Project
- Add your changes
- Project -> Export As Template -> Project Template (Add Template Name, Icon and preview Image)

More info [How to: Create project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019)